# Data is persisted but @JoinColumn = null

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to perform simple insert. There is Event and it contains tickets. Both Event and Ticket are saved when i save only Event but `@JoinColumn` does not generate id. It looks like this:

Event table
[image]

Tickets table:
[image]

Can someone tell me what is going on here? In my opinion, mappings are correct.

Base Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Long id;
}
```

Event Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event extends BaseEntity {

    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String description;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String img;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MusicGenre genre;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    Location location;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "event")
    Set<Ticket> tickets = new HashSet<>();

    public void addTicket(Ticket ticket) {
        this.tickets.add(ticket);
        ticket.setEvent(this);
    }
}
```

Ticket Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Ticket")
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket extends BaseEntity {

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private TicketType type;
    private Integer price;
    private Integer totalAmmount;
    private Integer inStock;

    @ManyToOne(
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.DETACH,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH
            }
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    Event event;

}
```

Notice that I am creating assosciation between these Entities via helper method in Event entity.

This is how I save them:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public EventsDTO saveAll(EventsDTO eventsDTO) {

    return EventsDTO.builder()
            .events(
                    eventsDTO.getEvents().stream()
                            .map(eventDTO -> eventMapper.eventDTOtoEvent(eventDTO))
                            .peek(event -> event.getTickets().forEach(event::addTicket))
                            .map(eventRepository::save)
                            .map(event -> eventMapper.eventToEventDTO(event))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).build();
}
```

Here is generated script:

```
Hibernate: insert into event (date, description, genre, img, location_id, title) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ticket (event_id, in_stock, price, total_ammount, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ticket (event_id, in_stock, price, total_ammount, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ticket (event_id, in_stock, price, total_ammount, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ticket (event_id, in_stock, price, total_ammount, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ticket (event_id, in_stock, price, total_ammount, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And Mapper implementation:

```
@Override
public Event eventDTOtoEvent(EventDTO eventDTO) {
    if ( eventDTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Event event = new Event();

    event.setId( eventDTO.getId() );
    event.setTitle( eventDTO.getTitle() );
    event.setDescription( eventDTO.getDescription() );
    event.setDate( eventDTO.getDate() );
    event.setImg( eventDTO.getImg() );
    event.setGenre( eventDTO.getGenre() );
    event.setLocation( locationDTOToLocation( eventDTO.getLocation() ) );
    event.setTickets( ticketDTOSetToTicketSet( eventDTO.getTickets() ) );

    return event;
}

   protected Set<Ticket> ticketDTOSetToTicketSet(Set<TicketDTO> set) {
        if ( set == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<Ticket> set1 = new HashSet<Ticket>( Math.max( (int) ( set.size() / .75f ) + 1, 16 ) );
        for ( TicketDTO ticketDTO : set ) {
            set1.add( ticketDTOToTicket( ticketDTO ) );
        }

        return set1;
    }

   protected Ticket ticketDTOToTicket(TicketDTO ticketDTO) {
        if ( ticketDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

        ticket.setId( ticketDTO.getId() );
        ticket.setType( ticketDTO.getType() );
        ticket.setPrice( ticketDTO.getPrice() );
        ticket.setTotalAmmount( ticketDTO.getTotalAmmount() );
        ticket.setInStock( ticketDTO.getInStock() );
        ticket.setEvent( eventDTOtoEvent( ticketDTO.getEvent() ) );

        return ticket;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `peek` that is only to be used for logging stuff. Instead you should be falling `addTicket` in y9our `eventDTOtoEvent` method.

Comment: why using .`peek(event -> event.getTickets().forEach(event::addTicket))` 
if tickets are all ready bind to event , hibernate will autmaticly set id event to ticket

Comment: Have you had a look at the generated SQL statements?

Comment: Removing peek does not work also and I have added sql statement.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using MapStruct here

Comment: Then configure that appropriately by specifying, `PREFER_ADDER` on the `@Mapper`.

Comment: @MateuszGebroski can you show us this method's `eventMapper.eventDTOtoEvent(eventDTO)` code?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz added.

Comment: It looks like you have a cyclic method call: `eventDTOtoEvent` and `ticketDTOToTicket`. `ticket.setEvent( eventDTOtoEvent( ticketDTO.getEvent() ) );` will call `eventDTOtoEvent` with the same event as in the method, which will call `ticketDTOToTicket` for each ticket again.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code. First one is in `ticketDTOToTicket()` method in your mapper. Here in the following statement:

```
ticket.setEvent( eventDTOtoEvent( ticketDTO.getEvent() ) );
```

You are creating a new `Event` object reference for each `Ticket` object. Which is different from the one which is being persisted. Each `Ticket` object should be referring to the same parent `Event` object reference. You should store the parent `Event` object reference in a variable and then assign the same reference to all the `Ticket` objects.

And the second issue is with the following line:

```
.peek(event -> event.getTickets().forEach(event::addTicket))
```

Here you are looping on the `Set<Ticket> tickets` and adding them back to the same `HashSet<>()` here:

```
public void addTicket(Ticket ticket) {
    this.tickets.add(ticket);
    ticket.setEvent(this);
}
```

Which will obviously do nothing as `Set` won't add the duplicate element. You should completely remove this.

**Verdict:**

> The actual problem with your code is that each `Ticket` object is not
>   referring to the same parent `Event` object reference instead each of
>   them is referring to the different object reference as described above. Fixing this issue
>   will resolve your problem.

Comment: `You are creating a new Event object reference for each Ticket object. Which is different from the one which is being persisted.` - in terms of DB, it's the same objects, as their ID are the same.

Comment: @Vusal if he stores or passes the reference of the parent `Event` object say in `event` variable. He should assign the same `event` variable to all the `Ticket` objects like this: `ticket.setEvent(event);`. Then it will be correctly persisted.

Comment: And about your statement: `in terms of DB, it's the same objects, as their ID are the same.`- ID of `Event` object is yet to be generated which will be generated when it is persisted in the database. Since none of the `Ticket` objects is referring to this `Event` object which is being persisted that's why `event_id` is saved as `NULL`.

Comment: if you have a tables A and B, and A is a parent for B, so A can have multiple Bs, and in your code you write something like this: ` A a1 = new A(); A a2 = new A(); a1.setId(1); a2.setId(1); B b1 = new B(); B b2 = new B(); b1.setA(a1); b2.setA(a2); ` - then in the database both records `b1` and `b2` will have the same parent id, which is 1 in this case. So, you don't have to use the same Java object as a parent. You can check it yourself or I can provide simplest spring app

Comment: Here you are manually setting the IDs to 1 for both objects. So both will be persisted. What if we let the Hibernate automatically assign the ID with `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY` and now we only persist `a1` in DB. What will happen now?

Comment: It doesn't matter who assigns the value. The idea is both a1 and a2 have the same id value. If the id is the same for Java object, then in terms if DB it's the same records.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public EventsDTO saveAll(EventsDTO eventsDTO) {

    return EventsDTO.builder()
            .events(
                    eventsDTO.getEvents().stream()
                            .map(eventDTO -> eventMapper.eventDTOtoEvent(eventDTO))
                            .map(eventRepository::save)
                            .map(event -> eventMapper.eventToEventDTO(event))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).build();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public Event eventDTOtoEvent(EventDTO eventDTO) {
    if ( eventDTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Event event = new Event();

    event.setId( eventDTO.getId() );
    event.setTitle( eventDTO.getTitle() );
    event.setDescription( eventDTO.getDescription() );
    event.setDate( eventDTO.getDate() );
    event.setImg( eventDTO.getImg() );
    event.setGenre( eventDTO.getGenre() );
    event.setLocation( locationDTOToLocation( eventDTO.getLocation() ) );
    event.setTickets( ticketDTOSetToTicketSet( eventDTO.getTickets(), event ) );

    return event;
}

protected Set<Ticket> ticketDTOSetToTicketSet(Set<TicketDTO> dtos, Event event) {
    if ( dtos == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    return dtos.stream().map(d -> ticketDTOToTicket(d, event)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

protected Ticket ticketDTOToTicket(TicketDTO ticketDTO, Event event) {
    if ( ticketDTO == null ) {
    return null;
    }

    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

    ticket.setId( ticketDTO.getId() );
    ticket.setType( ticketDTO.getType() );
    ticket.setPrice( ticketDTO.getPrice() );
    ticket.setTotalAmmount( ticketDTO.getTotalAmmount() );
    ticket.setInStock( ticketDTO.getInStock() );
    ticket.setEvent(event);

    return ticket;
}
```

FYI: It's better to return an empty collection instead of `null` from methods, which return type is `Collection`.